# Running Julia on VSCode

Tags: julia, visual-studio-code

I have been using Julia on VS Code for a few weeks now. Everytime I run something, I would get whatever is happening displayed on the output terminal at the bottom. For instance, if it's running on a block of package imports such as

```
using Plots
using CSV
```

I would get that in the terminal at the bottom. Today, when I open VS Code, none of that happens. I just get a final output of whatever it is is at the end of the whole file. I can't see which part of the file is running nor do I even get the

```
>julia
```

which is usually there when something is not running. I'm quite new to the whole thing so I don't even know if this is the right way to describe the problem.

Earlier it used to say `Julia: Evaluating` or something at the bottom left, when something was running. Now it doesn't say that as well.

Edit: These are screenshots.
[image: This is when the file is running]

This is when the file is running

[image: This is when no command is running and the number if the output of rand() but I have defined functions above and I can't tell if they have been defined or look at the output for that.]

This is when no command is running and the number if the output of rand() but I have defined functions above and I can't tell if they have been defined or look at the output for that.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your VS code window?

Comment: What happens if you cursor over a Julia line and press `Alt-Enter`?

Comment: @logankilpatrick I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou same thing when I try to press `Shift-Enter` or `Ctrl-Enter` or when I manually select a block of code and then try to run it. No visual signal of something running at all, with exactly the same thing I've described above.

Comment: [See what the command should be with Alt-Enter](https://i.imgur.com/7idmQyE.png) Do you have this option from the command palette?

Comment: @newtothis please link to image file in the screenshot. Use the paste image button in the [edit] screen for that. You linked an imgur album.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I hope it is okay now. I have directly added the images. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Check what the execution results settings are

[image: fig]

mine are results-inline and errors in REPL, but I think you want to have only REPL results.

With in-line results, you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> and get instant feedback for each line

[image: fig2]

So you know that each line is processed and what the results are.

Comment: It was set to both, but I tried setting it to REPL. Now, the terminal window at the bottom doesn't come up at all. I tried setting it back to both, and still no difference.